# How to use a ZBuffer with simple polygons?

Tags: 3d, rasterizing, zbuffer

I have been writing a simple 3d renderer, and have been looking into draw order. The engine renders 3d polygons (groups of 3d points that are in correct drawing order) into 2d space, returning a list of 2d points that represent the projection of a given polygon. My method for doing so may be a bit unorthodox because I wanted to see if I would be able to do it myself, so I have attached my code for projection below:

```
public class Camera {
/*position is the position of the camera, x, y, z;
cameraRotation is the rotation of the camera, in the order of rotation about x, rotation about y, rotation about z
the camera initially faces the +x direction
*/
private double focalAngle;
private double[] position, cameraRotation, cameraDirectionVector, cameraXVector, cameraZVector;
private double[][][] rotationMatrices = new double[3][3][3];
private double[][] compoundedRotationMatrices;

public Camera(double[] positionIn, double[] cameraRotationIn, double focalAngleIn){
    position = positionIn;
    focalAngle = focalAngleIn;
    cameraRotation = cameraRotationIn;
    updateRotation();
}

private void updateRotation(){
    updateRotationMatrices();
    updateCameraDirectionVector();
}

private void updateRotationMatrices(){
    compoundedRotationMatrices = Matrix.getCompoundedRotationMatrix(cameraRotation[0], cameraRotation[1], cameraRotation[2]);
}

private void updateCameraDirectionVector(){
    double[] xVector = {1,0,0};
    double[] yVector = {0,-1,0};
    double[] zVector = {0,0,1};
    cameraDirectionVector = Matrix.vecMultiply(compoundedRotationMatrices, xVector);
    cameraXVector = Matrix.vecMultiply(compoundedRotationMatrices, yVector);
    cameraZVector = Matrix.vecMultiply(compoundedRotationMatrices, zVector);
}

public ArrayList<int[][]> getPolygonProjections(ArrayList<double[][]> polySets, double screenWidth, double screenHeight){
   ArrayList<int[][]> outPoints = new ArrayList();
   for(int i = 0; i < polySets.size(); i++){
       int[][] polyPoints = new int[2][polySets.get(i).length];
       /*in the calculation of proejctions, divide by zeros and NaNs can pop up,
       polygonsLegitimate boolean keeps track of whether the polygon being drawn can be drawn without error,
       and the while loop stops calcuating the polygon once it determines it cannot be properly drawn
       */
       boolean polygonsLegitimate = true;
       int j = 0;
       while(j < polyPoints[0].length && polygonsLegitimate){
           int[] xy = getVectorProjection(polySets.get(i)[j], screenWidth, screenHeight);
           if(xy != null){
               polyPoints[0][j] = xy[0];
               polyPoints[1][j] = xy[1];

           }else{
               polygonsLegitimate = false;
           }
           j++;
       }
       if(polygonsLegitimate){
           outPoints.add(polyPoints);
       }
   }
   return outPoints;
}

private int[] getVectorProjection(double[] vector, double screenWidth, double screenHeight){
    double[] subVector = Vector.subtract(vector, position);
    double zDepth = getZDepthOfVector(subVector);
    if(zDepth > 0){
        double sliceSize = getSliceSizeAtDepth(zDepth);
        double cameraXProj = Vector.dot(subVector, cameraXVector);
        double cameraZProj = Vector.dot(subVector, cameraZVector);
        double xPercent = (cameraXProj+(sliceSize/2))/sliceSize;
        double zPercent = (cameraZProj+(sliceSize/2))/sliceSize;
        int[] xy = {(int)(xPercent * screenWidth),(int)((((1-zPercent) * screenWidth))-(screenHeight/2))};
        return xy;
    }
    return null;
}

public double getZDepthOfVector(double[] vector){
    return Vector.dot(cameraDirectionVector, vector);
}

private double getSliceSizeAtDepth(double zDepth){
    return 2.0*Math.cos(focalAngle)*zDepth;
}
```

Currently, I determine draw order by sorting the three dimensional polygons by the distance of the closest corner of the polygon to the camera, then drawing in the order of farthest polygons to closest polygons. However, because draw order is solely determined based on the distance of the closest point on the polygon to the camera, there are a few cornercases that prevent the algorithm from working correctly sometimes, as shown in this video:

https://youtu.be/olTOTOCw42M

I've done a lot of research on Z Buffer, and the concept is simple enough -- actually very similar to what I am doing. To my understanding, for each rendered pixel, all points that render on the same pixel are compared and the closest by z depth from the camera is displayed. However, given that in this case the only points I am working with are the ones that make up the corner of each polygon, I don't know a good way to go about comparing the z depth of any points that are contained within the polygons and not only at the corners.

I have two possible solutions to this issue:

1) Split each polygon into multiple smaller polygons. When I was mocking up a renderer in python, I never added in a Z Depth sorting, but I did divide each polygon into multiple smaller polygons so that I could light each polygon individually very easily, and the result is shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9quC.jpg

However, this is very expensive, as many projected points are projected multiple times since their value was determined by calculating the projections of neighboring polygons. Maybe there is a legitimate way to go about this, but it seemed too crude to me to be correct.

2) Find the plane that each 3d polygon lies on, bound it to the shape of the polygon, then solve for the intersections of individual scan-lines oriented through a view angle with those planes, then choosing the intersection with the closest z depth to the camera to display at that scan-line's pixel. That way, rather than the points of each polygon being projected then filled using java's polygon filling method, each pixel would be rendered individually. However, I am unsure how to "bound" a plane so that it would not extend past the border of the polygon, and it is a bit tricky for me to understand because the math is a bit too advanced for me currently. If this is the way it should be done, I can learn it, I just wanted to make sure it was a viable method beforehand.

3) Split each polygon into a set of many points rather than into smaller polygons: I figured this method would be flawed because the number of points necessary for a good render (i.e. one 3d point per pixel, no need to have multiple 3d points on the same polygon shape render onto the exact same pixel, or to have too few 3d points so that pixels are "skipped" in the rendering process) varies by the z depth, and the formula for calculating where to place these points seems difficult to formulate and expensive to run every time the camera is moved.

Answer (score 1):

Use ordering tables, the algorithm used by the Playstation 1.

Divide the Z Range into N equal-size parts.

- Create an array of N pointers to polygons.
- Every frame, clear that array to zero.
- For every triangle you want to draw:

  - Calculate the corresponding Z-Index i.
  - Insert it into Order[i] like with a linked list.
- Go through the array in reverse (back to front), painting triangles as you traverse

**C code**

```
Triangle *Order[256];

void Clear() {
    memset(Order,0,sizeof(Order));
}

void Insert(Triangle *tri) {
    int index = (tri->averageZ-zNear) * 256 / (zFar - zNear);
    tri->next = Order[index];
    Order[index] = tri;
}

void Paint() {
    for(int i=255;i>=0;i--)
        for(Triangle *tri=Order[i];tri;tri=tri->next)
            DrawTriangle(tri);
}
```

Source: Fabien "ryg" Giesen (of Farbrausch fame) has a talk titled "When lightspeed is not fast enough" where he presents this idea including this code.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Tackling this problem in 2021.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misinterpreting the Z Buffer idea and the closest to the truth is your solution no. 3) - splitting your polygons to single pixels.

The Z Buffer works per-pixel and yes, there're a lot of Z comparisons but it's just how it works. You can't simplify it to use only specific vertices of your polygons.

I assume you have some grid of let's say 'Color' structures that you're going to fill with your rendering. This will be your target image. You need to add another grid of floats, with the same size - this will be your Z Buffer. On start you fill your Z Buffer with some big value, like 1000000.

Ignore sorting of polygons for now - the Z Buffer will solve it for you. You can add sorting later to test performance differences between different drawing orders but it's not needed to make it work.

Now you need the rasterization stage, where you pass your polygon corners and get back the list of all pixels covered by this polygon. You may compute it using scan-lines, as you've mentioned in 2). I'd suggest you to write rasterization just for a single triangle and split all your polys into triangles, this will make your code simpler. You may return a list of pixels from this stage if you want to (list will be slow in this case but it's fine for learning purposes. It would be better to fill the pixel grids directly at this stage, instead of accumulating those data in memory) but you need one important change - pixels need correct Z value, besides of X and Y.

When you have such list of rasterized pixels you just put them into the pixel grid and that's where the Z testing occurs. Iterate over every pixel and: Read the current Z value from the Z Buffer, using pixel screen position (X,Y). If the value is bigger than current pixel's Z then write pixel color in color buffer and pixel Z in Z Buffer.

Comment: This sheds a little more light on my issue, but how can I individually compute the Z value of a 3d point on a polygon painted at a certain pixel? I understand that a ray is cast from the camera's position through the angle that intersects the x and y position of a given pixel, but how can I determine the Z depth where this ray through the pixel intersects the polygon (which is only a list of 3D points at each corner)?

Comment: For clarification, in option 3, I actually was talking about dividing the 3d polygon points into many 3d points in such a way that one point would be devoted to one pixel on the screen once it is projected. However, I wasn't sure about how to go about this (and it appears to be incorrect as well) -- from what I can tell, rather than splitting the polygon up into multiple 3d points, instead you are telling me to draw it as I am now using only its corners, then determine what the Z depth of the polygon at each drawn pixel of the polygon afterward, then do Z depth comparisons with that.

Comment: You compute pixel Z from polygon vertices by interpolating their Z values. Raycast would be much slower for this. Split your polys into triangles and think about triangles since now. Now you're drawing a triangle, which has all 3 corners on the screen, each with X,Y,Z values. For every pixel inside of this triangle you can interpolate the Z value using distances of pixel to corners. It's called barycentric coordinates and you can read about it here https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/rasterization-practical-implementation/perspective-correct-interpolation-vertex-attributes

Comment: Regarding option 3) I know you wanted to split poly to per-pixel objects but I don't know how to do this to get perfect 1-1 match between 'points' and pixels. I've said about this only because effectively you'd be comparing Z per-pixel and Z Buffer works per-pixel. But don't go this way, just rasterize entire triangles, but compare Z for every pixel separately. BTW: There's also a topic called 'perspective correction' but don't start with it until you see the problem by yourself :) it uses more complicated math but better start simple and then improve...

Comment: Thank you for your help! As far as I can tell, it is working correctly (although it is very slow): https://youtu.be/VT-x7l9qe-0. Right now, I am using Java's Polygon.contains() method to test if a pixel is inside of the projected polygon, so perhaps that is where I should first start if I were to speed this up.

Comment: Yeah, Polygon tests are probably one of the slowest things here, you could replace it by proper rasterization. Try also replacing polygons with triangles, this may help. Then you could drop returning a list of points contained in Polygon - just do Z testing and writing pixel just after the Polygon.contains() test.